# numbers not getting added together node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to store prices of products in sessions, and if a product is clicked twice, the price is should be added and shown in the session, but for some reason when I am trying to add two number , for example 15 + 15, it adds like 01515, I am not sure why this is happening.

Here is the .hbs file where the addition of a product starts.

```
{{# each products}}
    <div class="row">
        {{# each this}}
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="{{this.imagePath}}" alt="..." class="img-responsive">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>{{this.title}}</h3>
                        <p>{{this.description}}</p>
                        <div class="clearfix">
                            <div class="price pull-left">${{this.price}}</div>
                            <a href="/add-to-cart/{{this._id}}" class="btn btn-sucess pull-right" role="button">Add to cart</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

After add to cart button is pressed, here is the route and model,

**route**

```
router.get('/add-to-cart/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    var productId = req.params.id;
    var cart = new Cart(req.session.cart ? req.session.cart : {});

    Product.findById(productId, function(err, product) {
        if (err) {
            return res.redirect('/');
        }
        cart.add(product, product.id);
        req.session.cart = cart;
        console.log(req.session.cart);
        res.redirect('/');
    });
});
```

Model

```
module.exports = function Cart(oldCart) {
    this.items = oldCart.items || {};
    this.totalQty = oldCart.totalQty || 0;
    this.totalPrice = oldCart.totalPrice || 0;

    this.add = function(item, id) {
        var storedItem = this.items[id];
        if (!storedItem) {
            storedItem = this.items[id] = {item: item, qty: 0, price: 0};
        }
        storedItem.qty++;
        storedItem.price = storedItem.item.price * storedItem.qty;
        this.totalQty++;
        this.totalPrice += storedItem.item.price;
    };


    this.generateArray = function() {
        var arr = [];
        for (var id in this.items) {
            arr.push(this.items[id]);
        }
        return arr;
    };
};
```

I tried to log in the console to see whats happening while adding the numbers, it shows like this

```
    Cart {
  items: 
   { '5855c55482d8722419e21a7d': { item: [Object], qty: 1, price: 15 },
     '5855c55482d8722419e21a7f': { item: [Object], qty: 1, price: 15 } },
  totalQty: 2,
  totalPrice: '01515',
  add: [Function],
  reduceByOne: [Function],
  removeItem: [Function],
  generateArray: [Function] }
```

I am very new to node js, and I am not sure what is going wrong with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your module, change this line

```
this.totalPrice = oldCart.totalPrice || 0;
```

to be something like this

```
this.totalPrice = parseInt(oldCart.totalPrice, 10) || 0;
```

You should also change

```
this.totalPrice += storedItem.item.price;
```

to be something like

```
this.totalPrice += parseInt(storedItem.item.price);
```

The issue here is that both `this.totalPrice` and `storedItem.item.price` are strings when you first get it from your request — `this.totalPrice` being a string because `oldCart.totalPrice` will come back to you as a string.

This is causing coercion on your `storedItem.item.price` to a string when you add them together:

```
this.totalPrice += storedItem.item.price;
// string += string => concatenated string
```

Comment: I thought this answer might work, but it did not unfortunately.  I am very confused now.

Comment: @MasnadNihit see my updated answer — I think both variables are actually strings so we need to make them numbers

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! It worked! 
If its okay I would like to ask you two questions.
1)  oldCart.totalPrice, 10 <--  What does the 10 do.
2) Is there a way to debug this problems? I am not sure if console.log can be used in such situations?

Comment: @MasnadNihit Glad I could help! And the `10` here is just to specify the radix of the conversion (the base of the number). You don't need it since 10 is the default, but it's generally good practice to always include. Reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: Thanks! 
Any suggestions on the debugging?

Comment: @MasnadNihit To answer your second question, generally if you expect two numbers to be added together but they're being concatenated instead, that's a good sign that at least one of them are most likely strings. At this point you can check to see if that's true (by attempting to convert them to numbers like we did here) and try to figure out why that is in the first place to help debug future problems

Answer (score 1):

Its seems you concat a string value ! 
try to cast/force the integer type before do any mathematical action

```
const string1 = '123'
const string2 = '233'

console.log(string1 + string2)     //123233

console.log(parseInt(string1) + parseInt(string2))     //356
```

Always verify if your parseInt do not return a NaN ;)

Comment: Thanks for the comment but it does not help me understand what mistake I made. Could you help me in a way in which you tell me how to fix it? 
Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

oldcart.totalPrice would be giving you string so the value are getting concatenated.
instead of 
`this.totalPrice = oldCart.totalPrice || 0;`

you could use

`this.totalPrice = Number(oldCart.totalPrice) || 0;`